# How to stop an event for raising

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two fields, one textbox and one div element.
I have an `onblur` event for textbox, and an `onclick` event for div element.
When I click the div element the textbox's `onblur` event occurs and not the `onclick` event of div element. How to suppress the `onblur` event when I click on the div element?

Comment: Does the click event occurs after the onblur?

Answer (score 0):

try to use a semafore.

if the click event is triggered set the semafore to true and check the value in the blur event call. if true - do not perform the action.

after successfully performing the click event reset the semafore to false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do and is it right way or not.
But this will solve your problem by using flag named "f":

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var f = 0;
    function f1() {
        if (f == 0)
            alert('blur');
    }
    function f2() {
        alert('click');
    }
    function f3() {
        f = 1;
    }
    function f4() {
        f = 0;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" onblur="f1();" />
    <div onclick="f2();" onmouseover="f3();" onmouseout="f4();">
        Click Me!
    </div>
</body>
```

Good luck!